# How do I get my RoutePrefix to appear instead of the Controller name?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5, swagger-ui

I'm using Swashbuckle 5.5.3 for internal documentation of an API built using Web API 2. I'm using attribute routing and have added `[Route]` and `[RoutePrefix]` attributes to my controllers. I can view the swashbuckle / swagger generated page and I see the documentation I expect. The problem is Swagger displays the controller name instead of the preferred `[RoutePrefix]`.

For example, using the snippet included below, Swagger will display `ABCDEF` instead of `XYZ`.

```
[RoutePrefix("XYZ")]
public class ABCDEFController : ApiController
{
}
```

On the Swagger page, if I expand the `ABCDEF` controller and test the methods under it, the displayed URI and behavior is correct. It seems like the only issue is incorrect display of the controller name.

How do I display the `RoutePrefix` instead of the controller name?

Comment: Is attribute routing enabled? `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes` in the *WebApiConfig* file

Comment: @Nkosi - Yes. The API works as expected, including the routes.